# Eclipse auto completion with generic classes and static methods

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, autocomplete

For generic classes, I usually prefer static methods instead of constructors to avoid tedious redundant type parameters (example given below for clarification).

But when using auto completion, Eclipse always suggests the type parameter, like:

`example` (ctrl+space) `Example<T>`

I then have to remove the `<T>` manually and instead add my static method, like `Example.new()`. Is there a possiblity to change this behaviour or a completely different convenient shortcut for a better workflow? (I am still working with Eclipse 3, has this been changed in 4?)

```
static final class Example<T> {

    /** Private, use factory method instead. */
    private Example() {
    }

    public static <T> Example<T> create() {
        return new Example<T>();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Example<Integer> example = Example.create();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If immediately after hitting (ctrl-space), you hit the backspace key twice, Eclipse will remove the entire type argument clause. This was implemented to address https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=301990.

It's not perfect - I would rather eclipse only add the type argument clause when the type name is preceded by new, but it at least makes it manageable.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be rather new! However, I assume the link you posted is a totally different issue?

Answer (score 4):

Having been bothered by this forever I've just noticed that if you complete by pressing '.' rather than 'return' it completes to the type name.  So

- `Exam<ctrl+space>.` completes to `Example.` with the completion dialog open suggesting fields and methods of the class.
- `Exam<ctrl+space><return>` completes to `Example<T>` and closes the completion dialog.

I don't see any evidence of the backspace thing working.

Answer (score 3):

I think it was a bug in eclipse as seen here [Auto complete inserts type parameter placeholders too aggressively](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=283950)

And you can have a look at this it may help you [Eclipse and Generic Types](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-with-j2se50.htm)

Comment: Thank you for the ticket links, so I can at least track for any news on that issue!

Comment: Did you find any solution of your problem ?

Comment: No, still bugging me (beside other things). But I finally bought a license of IntelliJ and should finally make the switch.